# create an object from an existing json file using 'jq'

Tags: json, object, jq

I have a messages.json file

```
[
    {
        "id": "title",
        "description": "This is the Title",
        "defaultMessage": "title",
        "filepath": "src/title.js"
      },
      {
        "id": "title1",
        "description": "This is the Title1",
        "defaultMessage": "title1",
        "filepath": "src/title1.js"
      },
      {
        "id": "title2",
        "description": "This is the Title2",
        "defaultMessage": "title2",
        "filepath": "src/title2.js"
      },
      {
        "id": "title2",
        "description": "This is the Title2",
        "defaultMessage": "title2",
        "filepath": "src/title2.js"
      },
    ]
```

I want to create an object

```
{
    "title": "Dummy1",
    "title1": "Dummy2",
    "title2": "Dummy3",
    "title3": "Dummy4"
  }
```

from the top one.
So far I have

```
jq '.[] | .id' src/messages.json;
```

And it does give me the IDs
How do I add some random text and make the new object as above?

Can we also create a new JSON file and write the newly created object onto it using jq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output included "title3" so I'll assume that you intended that the second occurrence of "title2" in the input was supposed to refer to "title3".

With this assumption, the following jq program seems to do what you want:

```
map( .id )
| . as $in
| reduce range(0;length) as $i ({};
    . + {($in[$i]): "dummy\(1+$i)"})
```

In words, extract the values of .id, and then turn each into an object of the form: `{(.id) : "dummy\(1+$i)"}`

This uses string interpolation, and produces:

```
{
  "title": "dummy1",
  "title1": "dummy2",
  "title2": "dummy3",
  "title3": "dummy4"
}
```

#### reduce-free solution

```
map(.id )
| [., [range(0;length)]]
| transpose
| map( {(.[0]): "dummy\(.[1]+1)"})
| add
```

#### Output

> Can we also create a new json file and write the newly created object onto it using jq?

Yes, just use output redirection:

```
jq -f program.jq messages.json > output.json
```

#### Addendum

> I want a parent object "de" to the already created json file objects

You could just pipe either of the above solutions to: `{de: .}`

Comment: Where do ".title", ".create", ".edit" and ".delete" come from?  Maybe you should create a new SO question as there doesn't seem to be any connection between the original question and your new one.

Comment: fixed the names... 
This worked really well. Thanks. I have a slight enhancement to this and want the result json as "de": { "title": "dummy1", "title1": "dummy2", "title2": "dummy3", "title3": "dummy4" } . I tried editing the program.jq as . map(.id ) | [., [range(0;length)]] | transpose | map( "de" : {(.[0]): "dummy(.[1]+1)"}) | add but it gives me errors. Basically I want a parent object "de" to the already created json file objects

Comment: map(.id )
| [., [range(0;length)]]
| transpose
| {de: .}
| map( {(.[0]): "dummy\(.[1]+1)"})
| add .        does not work

Comment: No surprise there. See the addendum.

Comment: Would you be able to write the entire solution with {de: .} piped in

Comment: I said: piped into {de:.}.  That means: map(.id ) ... | add | {de:.}